# code optimization not working in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, optimization, alamofire

I am using Swift and `alamofire`.

How can I do code optimization? This is my post and put request for different api's:

```
func    getPDataFromURL(_ onCompletion:@escaping (Dictionary<String,    Any>)-> Void)
      {
      let token  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserLoginToken")
      let Usertype  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Usertype")
      let Userbranchid  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Userbranchid")

      let UrlStraing = FETCH_Parent_Profile_URL 

      print(UrlStraing)

            let url = URL(string: UrlStraing)!
      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url)
      urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
      urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
          let  userToken = "Token token=" + token! as String
          urlRequest.addValue(userToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
      Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
          switch(response.result) {
          case .success(_):
              if response.result.value != nil{
                  print(response.result.value!)
                  onCompletion(response.result.value! as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
              }
              break

          case .failure(_):
              print(response.result.error!)
              onCompletion(response.result.error as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
              break
          }
      }
}
```

And this is my second post request for another api:

```
func getSDataFromURL(_ onCompletion:@escaping  (Dictionary<String, Any>)-> Void)    {
      let token  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserLoginToken")
      let Usertype  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Usertype")
      let Userbranchid  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Userbranchid")

      let UrlStraing = FETCH_School_Info_URL + "branch_id=" + Userbranchid! + "&student_id=86&user_type=" + Usertype!

      print(UrlStraing)

      let url = URL(string: UrlStraing)!
      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url)
      urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
      urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
      let  userToken = "Token token=" + token! as String
      urlRequest.addValue(userToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
      Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
          switch(response.result) {
          case .success(_):
              if response.result.value != nil{
                  print(response.result.value!)
                  onCompletion(response.result.value! as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
              }
              break

          case .failure(_):
              print(response.result.error!)
              onCompletion(response.result.error as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
              break
          }
      }
}
```

And calling function in viewcontroller like this:

```
func SetUpSchoolUIProfiledata()    {
      Common.sharedInstance.StartActivity(view: self.view)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
      APIManager.sharedInstance.getSchoolProfileDataFromURL(){(userJson)->
Void in

          self.stop()
          let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(userJson)
          print("userJson userJson userJson userJson",userJson)

          print("swiftyJsonVar",swiftyJsonVar)

          let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()
          let info = swiftyJsonVar["info"].rawString()!

          let jsonData = info.data(using: .utf8)!
          let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])  as! Dictionary<String, Any>

          self.schoolName_lbl.text = dictionary?["name"] as? String
          self.add1_lbl.text = dictionary?["add_line1"] as? String
          print("imgURLstring  is ",self.imgURLstring)
          self.SetUpProfileImage()
      }
      }
}
```

how to create single function multiple post and get requests?

Comment: you can create singleton class to hit webservices and pass parameters and url for reusablilty

Answer (score 2):

You can create singleton class like this
when you want to call the web service, use this method

```
class DataProvider: NSObject {

    class var sharedInstance:DataProvider {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = DataProvider()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    let baseUrl:String = "http://192.168.1.25:3004/api3/v3/"



     func putData( parameter:[String:String], url:String, _ successBlock:@escaping ( _ response: JSON )->Void , errorBlock: @escaping (_ error: NSError) -> Void ){

            let path =  baseUrl + url
            print(path)
            print(parameter)

            let headers = ["authorization": AppData().token]

            Alamofire.request(path, method: .put, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        successBlock(json)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    errorBlock(error as NSError)
                }
            }
    }
```

call like this

```
DataProvider.sharedInstance.putData(parameter: parameter, url: "users/account/update", { (response) in
            print(response)

            if response["status"].stringValue == "200" {
                Utility.showMessageDialog(onController: self, withTitle: "", withMessage: response["message"].stringValue)
            }


        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: i have done already same but for every url i am createing another function.

Comment: @kishore create only one method call from where you want to use this for ex:- you have 4 view controller then use this method every view controller

Comment: please see above my code getParentDataFromURL and getSchoolProfileDataFromURL are two 'post' functions i am using in two different view controllers, and for two functions apis also different. @ios singh

Comment: @kishore I read your code, Please first of all create singleton class for reusability for call the webservice. then pass the parameters and URL in web service method and use easily

Comment: i created singleton class see in my calling fun.